# GLSL - length function

Tags: glsl, shader, webgl

From the GLSL documentation (https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/length.xhtml), the length function "calculate the length of a vector".

But I don't get it, what does "length" mean here ?

For instance:

```
length(.5); // returns .5
length(1.); // returns 1.
```

So how and why are you supposed to use this function?

Comment: Just in case you should probably be aware but the reference pages you linked to are for OpenGL GLSL 4 which is not what WebGL uses. WebGL1 uses GLSL ES 1.0, WebGL2 adds GLSL ES 3.00. In this particular case the docs for length are similar but for other things different specs, different features.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

See [The OpenGL ES Shading Language](https://www.khronos.org/files/opengles_shading_language.pdf)

8 Built-in Functions, page 63

> When the built-in functions are specified below, where the input arguments (and corresponding output) can be `float`, `vec2`, `vec3`, or `vec4`, *genType* is used as the argument.

8.4 Geometric Functions, page 68

> ```
> float length (genType x)
> ```
>
> Returns the length of vector x, i.e.,
>   [image]

This means the result of `length(.5)` is:

```
sqrt(0.5 * 0.5) = 0.5
```

and the result of `length(1.)` is

```
sqrt(1.0 * 1.0) = 1.0
```

Answer (score 1):

The documentation uses 'genType' for generic type and mostly it shows all functions accepting this, meaning that it could be any of the base types.

I don't know why it is not more specific when it clearly says that it's a vector operation.

I think most probably it simply returns the input value if it's a 1-dimensional vector which is just one number and it will calculate the length of 2-,3- dimension vectors properly.

Here the length means the  euclidean distance of a vector, not the length or count of the element's it has.

Comment: *"it simply returns the input value if it's a 1-dimensional vector"* well not if its negative because euclidean distance is always positive.

Comment: If anything, for a 1-d vector v, it will return `abs(v)`